# Help with Custom Visualforce Community Landing Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, controller

So I am working on creating a Custom Visual force page to use as the Community Landing Page, and I want it to be that when a user logs in it takes them directly to their Account in Salesforce. I have brought their Account ID on to the User record to hopefully help with this.

I am writing a Controller in Apex to attempt to get that value and make it the Account we load into to, but when I go to the Community I am getting the below error:

> Error: Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page.
>   Please email us if you need to get in touch

[image: Error]

Here is my Controller:

```
public class CommunityLandingPageController {   
    public Account account { get; set; }

    public CommunityLandingPageController() {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website
                   FROM Account WHERE Id in (SELECT AccountId FROM User)];
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update account;
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my Visual Force page:

```
<apex:page controller="CommunityLandingPageController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Congrats {!$User.FirstName}">
            You belong to Account Name: <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Nowhere in your query are you getting the current user. Take a look at the UserInfo apex class and update your query to get the AccountId from the current User instead of from all User records in the system.

Comment: I looked into that, but cannot see anything about getting a Custom Field value from the User object. What would I need to change for this?

Comment: Which custom field are you trying to retrieve? I don't see any custom fields in the query you posted above. I think just updating your query to User from `SELECT AccountId FROM User` (which will get all users in your Salesforce) to `SELECT AccountId FROM User WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()` will limit your query down to just getting the current running user.